# Evaluate $\iint_{S}x^2y^2zdS$ on positive side of lower half of $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Evaluate $$\iint_{S}x^2y^2zdS$$where $S$ is positive side of lower half of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$

I learnt how to calculate surface integral but in this question,I can't understand what is meant by positive side if we take lower half.

In the textbook,it is given as "It will be assumed that the positive side of a surface projects on the positive side of coordinate planes" ,but I don't get it.

Comment: I don't understand this either. Nevertheless, notice that this integral is symmetric with respect to $x\rightarrow -x$ and $y\rightarrow -y$, so whatever quarter you choose in the lower half part ($z<0$) - the integral will yield the same result.

Comment: @eranrechesI have added what is given in the book

Comment: Still confuses me. What book are you using?

Comment: @eranreches Its "Mathematical Analysis" by S C Malik

Comment: I looked for it online and it's pretty hard to find.